# Getting null pointer exception- dont know where I am going wrong

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to code in selenium and I am getting a null pointer exception my code.

Please check the image attached. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQGc3.png)

For example when I create

```
webdriver wd = new Chromedriver()
wd.get("http://facebook.com");
```

and when I used `wd` in another method to find element then I am getting error.

Comment: The instance variable wd is never set to anything. Either make month static and pass it in or write a constructor that creates the driver and sets the instance variable

Comment: Please, put code in text format next time, do not mess over images

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize `field wd`. You initialized `local variable` instead, that is viable only inside main method. 
[image: your_image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to something like the following, it will be enough for your learning exercises.

```
public class Learning_3 {
    static WebDriver wd;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\Users\\hsundara\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
        wd = new ChromeDriver();
        wd.get("http://www.facebook.com");

        month();
    }

    public static month() {
        WebElement element = wd.findElement(By...);
    }

}
```